# PhpSpreadsheet - api document can't find Spreadsheet and worksheet class

Tags: phpspreadsheet

in the API documentation - https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/, I have see the spreedsheet and worksheet class reference， but now， they have missed，how can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like yourself, I cannot find a page with a reference for the Spreadsheet class at present. However, you can find the Worksheet namespace here:

https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/namespaces/phpoffice-phpspreadsheet-worksheet.html

Unfortunately, it does not either appear to give a link to property or method reference information for the Worksheet class.

However there are various usage examples in the [main documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) though which may hold enough to answer some of your questions, and also other information scattered around GitHub, SO and other sites. If there is a specific burning question you need answered, create a separate SO post.